# Can we mention Number of Rows in flutter Gridview?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can we mention the **number of rows** in flutter **GridView** like **crossAxisCount**?

Answer (score 1):

you can user GridView.count, crossAxisCount are no of rows in your grid.

try below code :

```
GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount: 4,
   childAspectRatio: 1.0,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
   mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
   crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
   children: <String>[
      //Your Children's Widgets
   ]
)
```

Comment: can we Mention MainAxisCount?

Comment: what you want? no of rows or no of columns ?

Comment: grid view only accept crossAxisCount, because it will work left -> right , so mainAxisCount no possible

Comment: i want no of rows

Comment: Okay, if you have any problems, tell me

Comment: My Expected Output has come by change scroll direction to horizontal, Thank you

Comment: Great! You're Welcome

Answer (score 1):

> GridView and all other name constructors of GridView are take number of columns (crossAxisCount)  as input and no way to input directly number of rows as it starts paint from left, paints number of columns defined and again move to next row and repeat same until list is finished.

One way to do it by limiting number of data you want to display like if you are getting a list of 50 items and you know there will be 2 columns and you want to display only 10 rows then there will be only 20 items to be displayed so pass only those 20 items.

**Note** `GridView`s are scrollable by default

#### Solution

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<String> productItems = [
    'Macbook Pro 15inch',
    'Macbook Pro 16inch',
    'Macbook Pro 13inch',
    'Macbook Air',
    'Mac Pro',
    'Ipad Pro',
    'Ipad Air',
    'Apple Watch Gen 3',
    'Apple Watch Gen 5'
    'Pro Display XDR',
    'iMac',
    'iMac Pro',
    'Mac Mini'
  ];

  bool showMore;
  int initialCount;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    showMore = false; // to show all elements or not
    initialCount = 8; // determines how many elements from list to show
  }

  changeShowMore() {
    setState(() {
      showMore = !showMore;
      if (showMore) {
        // if showMore is true than all elements 
        // from list will be taken and displayed
        initialCount = productItems.length;
      } else {
        // if showMore is false than display upto 8 
        // or any calculation you want to add here depending 
        // upon your crossAxisCount and number of elements in list
        initialCount = 8; 
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        children: productItems
            .map(
              (String name) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(name),
                ),
              ),
            )
            .take(initialCount) // take only upto initialcount
            .toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => changeShowMore(),
        child: Text('All')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Copy and paste whole code in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether there is specific function for that but, I believe you can do it like `number of total items/number of items in the row`